# Space estimates for each table if compression is removed

Tags: sql-server, scripting, compression

I am trying to gather space estimates if compression is removed from tables in a database.  I started with a temp table and generated statements to execute `sp_estimate_data_compression_savings` as shown below:

```
insert into #TEMP2 
exec sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 'dbo', 'table_name',NULL,NULL,'none'
```

That command works fine, and inserts the size estimate into a temp table.  I am trying to wrap this into a `sp_MSforeachtable` statement:

```
declare @command varchar(1000)
select @command = 'insert into #temp2 exec sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 
    ''dbo'', ''?'', NULL, NULL, ''none'''
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command
```

This generates all table does not exist or you do not have permissions errors for every table in the database:

```
Msg 1088, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_estimate_data_compression_savings
Cannot find the object "[dbo].[table_name]" because it does not exist
or you do not have permissions.
```

I assumed the database context was being changed somewhere in the `sp_MSforeachtable` command so I tried adding `USE DBNAME` to the command as shown below, but that didn't seem to have any effect, and it generated the same errors.

```
declare @command varchar(1000)
select @command = 'USE DBNAME 
    insert into #pattemp2 
    exec sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 
        ''dbo'',''?'',NULL,NULL,''none'''
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command
```

Answer (score 3):

Because that will run

```
exec sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 'dbo','[dbo].[table_name]',NULL,NULL,'none'
```

instead of

```
exec sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 'dbo','table_name',NULL,NULL,'none'
```

Why?  Because sp_MSforeachtable is undocumented and you shouldn't be using it.  Write a cursor, or find a replacement on the internet.  eg

```
set nocount on
drop table if exists #results
create table #results
(
  object_name sysname,
  schema_name sysname,
  index_id int,
  partition_number int,
  [partition_number size_with_current_compression_setting(KB)] bigint,
  [size_with_requested_compression_setting(KB)] bigint,
  [sample_size_with_current_compression_setting(KB)] bigint,
  [sample_size_with_requested_compression_setting(KB)] bigint
)
declare @schema sysname
declare @table sysname

declare c cursor local static for 
    select schema_name(schema_id), name
    from sys.tables
    where type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
open c

fetch next from c into @schema, @table 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
   insert into #results
   exec sp_estimate_data_compression_savings @schema, @table,NULL,NULL,'none'

   fetch next from c into @schema, @table 
end
close c
deallocate c
select * from #results
```